# Wait executing a function until completes another

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a common class to get web service response. Now I want to assign the return value from the web service in my first view controller. But the problem is the assigning code in view controller executes before completes the web service response in swift common class. Therefore the array returns as an empty array. Can someone please give an idea to wait until completes the service call in swift.

Here is my sample code.
Common.swift class

```
static func getData() -> [returnArray] {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        // Request to get service data
        // Servce response
        let task = restObject.callObject.dataTask(with: requestObject, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            let object = getData(data)
            if let values = object {
                if values.count > 0 {
                    // Assign the values to global static array
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
        })
    // return the global static array
}
```

View controller class:
Inside didLoad function I'm calling the common class above function and access the returned array values. But it returns an empty array.

Comment: you do not want to *wait*, you need to register your class via some kind of "callback" or "completion handler".

Comment: Look into PromiseKit: https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: @shallowThought I updated the question with a sample code.

Comment: As @luk2302 wrote: Search for "swift3 completion handler"

Comment: Thank you very much.. Completion handler worked for me..

Answer (score 2):

Here I am creating a ServiceClass that is called from another class and hence, getting the call back by the swift block in:-
1) unReachable
2) handler

```
ServiceClass.instance().hitPostService(params, unReachable: {
   print("Connection Error. Please check your internet connection and try again.")
}) { (response) in
     if response != nil {
          print_debug(response)
     }
}
```

Another Controller that is ServiceClass.

```
func hitPostService(params:Dictionary<String,String>,unReachable:(() -> Void),handler:((Dictionary<String,AnyObject>?) -> Void)) {
        if networkReachable() {
            print_debug("Params:- \(params)")
            Alamofire.request(.POST, Constant.BASE_URL+params[Constant.kAPPEND_URL]!, parameters: params,encoding: .JSON)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .Success:
                        let result = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

                        handler(result!) //call handler block for data
                    case .Failure(let error):
                        print_debug(error)
                        handler(nil) //call handler block with nil
                    }
            }
        }
        else {
            unReachable() //call unrechable block
        }
    }
```

More information about the block you can get from http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/

Comment: Thank you but this didn't work for me.

Comment: Swift 2.2 and with alamofire its work fine..

Comment: Basically, you need to learn about blocks.